# Editing PostGIS multipoint table with QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, multipoint

I created an empty multipoint table in PostGIS and I want to fill it with hand-placed points in QGIS. I have connected them and checked that QGIS identifies the new layer as multipoint. I've got a problem:

1. I am unable to add multipoints neither adding parts to a point nor combining two or more points.

Comment: Is there a primary key on the table? Do you have the `insert` privilege on the table?

Comment: I do. However, I have edited my initial question, as the first problem was my fault.

Comment: I simply meant that I was able to open the DB in QGIS. The operation that you have done (select 3 points and merge them together) is what I can't, since the corresponding editor button is not activated. Perhaps it's a problem of the version (I use a Mac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table must have a primary key to allow proper editing. That was the problem.

Comment: You can accept your own answer with the checkbox